# passing char* back and forth between functions

Tags: c++, c

I have two functions and I'm trying to pass a buffer from one function to the other and have it modify the contents, but I cannot seem to get it to work..here is what i have:

```
void caller ()
{
    char *  datum;
    populate (&datum);
}

void populate (void * buf)
{
    unsigned char * datump;
    int dtsz;
    getData (datump,dtsz);   // This function puts "001" in datump and dtsz = 4 

    buf = new unsigned char[dtsz];
    memset(datumbuf,0,sizeof(buf));
    memcpy (buf,datump,dtsz);

}
```

When I debug through everything seems to be exactly like it should be until I get to memcpy. It does not seem like memcpy actually does anything.
The reason "datumbuf = new unsigned char[dtsz]" is done is because the "getData()" function returns each time with a different size depending on the data size, hence the size can't be statically assigned.

When I get back to the main "caller()" function, the "datum" contains junk.

Any ideas why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

Thanks

Comment: populate not use buf.

Comment: Firstly, `sizeof(buf)` is the size of a pointer, not the size of the allocated memory. Secondly, assigning to `buf` will only affect the local copy, causing a memory leak. If you plan on fixing this by making the parameter a `void**` so you can assign to `*buf`, you won't be able to implicitly pass in a `char**`.

Comment: First of all, `void * buf` should be `char **buf`. Second, your function doesn't make use of `buf` at all!

Comment: @chris, char** is perfectly convertible to void*.

Comment: @pvgoran, My bad, it's just `void**`. I'll edit my comment to put it with the third point.

Comment: @EdS. Isn't it implicit in C++ as well?

Comment: @pvgoran, Yes indeed, tested it to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

It's not C++, it's C. Use `std::string` and forget about such buffers if you're using C++.

You don't modify `buf` in `populate`. You don't allocate memory for datump (don't know what getData does).

Answer (score 2):

Your `populate` function should just *return* a pointer. that way everything is much easier.

```
char * populate()
{
  ...
  buf = new unsigned char[dtsz];
  ...
  return buf;
}
```

...and then you call it like this:

```
char * datum = populate()
```

your current code doesn't work because you're confused between value and reference parameters. You pass datum 'by reference' `populate(&datum)` but `populate treats it like a value parameter.

Answer (score 1):

That memset line is strange and wrong, `sizeof(datumbuf)` is the pointer size (4 or 8), not the arrays length.
If its 8, it will be writing over other stuff, since the array you describe is only 4 long. Still, I doubt thats your actual error.